# I need to upgrade me code for DRY and easy refactoring in future

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I need to move api/ prefix to main urls.py, cause it'll be easy to rename in one string later. And my reviewer ask me don't duplicate version in router, and write 'v1'once.

my main urls:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('posts.urls')),
]
```

my app urls:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from .views import CommentViewSet, PostViewSet
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('v1/posts', PostViewSet)
router.register(r'v1/posts/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comments',
                CommentViewSet, basename='Comment')
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

i tried:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts', PostViewSet, basename='posts')
router.register(r'posts/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comments', CommentViewSet,
                basename='comments')
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token),
    path('api/v1/', include(router.urls)),
```

but its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts/', PostViewSet, basename="post")
router.register(r'posts/(?P<post_id>\d+)/comments', CommentViewSet, basename='Comment')

URLS = [ path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)]
URLS += router.urls

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/v1/', include(URLS),
]
```